# How to calculate the percentage here?

Tags: percentages

I have a very very simple question, it relate to physics also

Assuming we have a device with efficiency 85%, how much should be the input power to achieve 100W power in the output?

Here is my problem:

Some people say you have to multiple 100, 1.15 time  because there are 15% losses

So we have

**100 x 1.15 = 115 W**

But some other people say you have to divide 100 by 0.85

So we have

**100 / 0.85 = 117.6 W**

Please help what is the true way?

Comment: If the input power is x, then (x)(85%)=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{Output}{Input}\times 100= \text{efficiency percentage}$$